# draw the scatterplot of 2 time series with different lengths

Tags: r

I need to draw a scatterplot of the 2 following data series in order to observe their correlation:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TSLA", from="2020-10-19")
getFX("BTC/USD", from="2020-10-19")
```

Though, the data frame of the BTC/USD has more observations because it is traded even in the weekend, while the stocks no. How can delete the rows in excess of BTCUSD? NB: the dates are set as row names, not as a column.

Thank you!!

Comment: You will have to provide some data, e.g. two weeks from each and copy/pasting the output from `dput()` to preserve the details of the data. When I run your code, the second line returns "TSLA" and the third line returns "BTC/USD", but no data.

Comment: I believe you can merge the two with an inner join, including dates common to both data sets...try `merge(TSLA, BTCUSD, join = "inner")`

Comment: @dcarlson I believe the xts objects should be in your environment...look to see if `TSLA` and `BTCUSD` (without hyphen) were created with above code...

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct!